# Cann't start MySQL on my Linux server with Centos 7 OS

Tags: centos, mysql

I have already installed MySQL in a Server (Centos 7) by the following commands:

```
yum install -y mysql
yum install -y mysql-server
yum install -y mysql-devel
```

After the installation, I type `mysql` and meet the error

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket 
'/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I think it is because I didn't started the MySQL service yet, so I type the command

```
service mysqld start
```

Then I get the message said that `Job for mariadb.service failed`

Here is the content of `/etc/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid
```

However, the file `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` is not existed in my server. BTW, SELINUX is disabled manually.

`mariadb.log` shows

```
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 50331648 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!
InnoDB: Possible causes for this error:
   (a) Incorrect log file is used or log file size is changed
   (b) In case default size is used this log file is from 10.0
   (c) Log file is corrupted or there was not enough disk space
   In case (b) you need to set innodb_log_file_size = 48M
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGIN failed.
[ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: innodb
[ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: http://stopdisablingselinux.com/ There is no need to disable SELinux. Certainly straight out of the box, services installed from official repos and no exotic config services will work the way you expect with SELinux enabled.  Please add the errors reported in `/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log` to your question. The `mysql.sock` will be created when Mysql is started. Is this a clean install or did you have a MySQL DB before this on this system?

Comment: Thanks for your remind and I attached some messages of  `mariadb.log`. It is a clean system with MySQL installed for the first time.

Comment: So? Did you check disk space? Size of the file and the contents of the conf file?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem, so I want to answer it myself. If this self-answering behavior is not appropriate, please make comments below.

Overall, I solve this problem by figuring issues listed in `/var/log/mariadb/maridb.log` file.

First, I remove the `./ib_logfile0`, which is pointed out beyond size limitation in the `log` file. Then, I try to `enable` + `start` mariadb with `systemctl`, fail again. `maridb.log` says `Incorrect information in file './mysql/proxies_priv.frm'`. By backuping the incorrect file and restarting the mysql, the maridb is finally OK.